# How to make chrome tab executed by selenium/chromedriver to not close

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

How does one make the google chrome tab to not close immediately after its opened.
Could use time.sleep or use a while loop in some type of way?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options)

driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it myself.
Use this

```
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
```